# Controller syntax Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, controller, ruby-on-rails-6

Having an issue with displaying only three posts on a page. Here is the closest I've gotten to getting the controller working with a param.

```
def index

    @Post = Post.all

    @Posts = Post.find.limit('3').order('date_posted')

  end
```

This is rendering a syntax error of sorts because it wants an ID, but I don't want to give it an ID, I want it to find the three most recent posts. How should I go about that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
def index
  @recent_posts = Post.limit(3).order(date_posted: :desc)
end
```

What's wrong in your code

- `all` gives you all the objects for a model
- `find` and `find_by` give you just one object which meet the id passed to `find` or the first one which meets the conditions passed to `find_by`

Comment: The view would change for this or no?
I have:

<% @posts.each do |post| %>

Comment: Use `@recent_posts` in the view. Or change in the action to `@posts`. As you wish :)

Comment: It's giving me a "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error now :/

Comment: the instance variable in your action and in the view need to be the same. and should work.

Comment: Nailed it >.< had one capitalized and not the other. Thanks for the help!